# Workspace API subtab showing Title as Loading

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning, workspaceapi

Even after setting the label in workspace api, I can see the label set to `Loading...` of the subtab. Below is the code I am using :

```
var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
            workspaceAPI.openTab({
                pageReference: {
                    "type": "standard__component",
                    "attributes": {
                        "componentName": "c__OpenSubTab"
                        //second aura component
                    },
                },
                focus: true
            }).then(function(subtabId){
                workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
                    tabId: subtabId,
                    label: "New Record"
                });
                workspaceAPI.setTabIcon({
                    tabId: subtabId,
                    icon: "action:new_account",
                    iconAlt: "New Account"
                });
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

I am using setTabLabel to set the `label="New Record"`, however I see `"Loading..."` How can I make sure that it shows the `title "New Record"` when the subtab opens

This Occurs only first time when the button is clicked to open the tab. When I click the button again the label loads properly. I have also tried the setTimeout function but it does not work.